# Production mode assetic

Tags: php, symfony, product, assetic

Hi i have some troubles when going in production mode with assetic ( 1st time  )

When i try to run this command

> php app/console assetic:dump --env-prod --no-debug

I get this message

> The source file "...." does not exist.

Well hell yeah assetic, this file does not exist ! not in my src/ folder , not in my web/ folder either. Is there some kind of assetic cache?

I had another file which sent me that error, it happened to disappear after i ran assets:install but not this time

I ran : cache:clear, cache:clear --env prod, assets:install,..

I have no idea what i'm doing. Thanks

Comment: just to make sure, because you have typo here: you should have `--env=prod` not `--env-prod`

Comment: thats weird because the console should have thrown an invalid options error for that.

Comment: my bad, i typed from head,  yeah i did env=prod ,  i have like 20 files dumped allready this is the 21th.. I'm not even sure i created a file in the folder displayed in the error and if i did it was at least 2 weeks ago. I even tried to create a file with the name but no

Answer (score 0):

And the solution is.. manually delete the cache

Comment: actually i took another folder, and the bug is back. I tried everything. Seems like there is a bug with the css and assetic. I delete the cache manually and everytime this ghost file is back.